# How do I transfer a number from a register to a label?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

So I have 2 files and one of them calls functions while the other holds the string functions. I'm trying to do a similar version to strcpy and it isn't quite working.

> copies a string into another memory location

It isn't specified where I have to put it, but I was thinking of an empty label. I have been looking online and trying different things, but I can't seem to find a way to store something inside a label. I get errors or nothing happens.

Function is file 1:

```
/*
    strcpy()
    Assumes string is in stack
    Copies string into copy and then puts it back into stack
*/
strcpy:
    POP     {R3}            @ Puts string in R3
    LDR     R3, =copy       @ Copy str into label
    PUSH    {R3}
    BX      LR
```

File 2

```
.global _start

_start:
    @ Load string then string len into stack
    LDR     r1, =str
    PUSH    {r1}
    BL      strcpy
    @ Print string
    MOV     R0, #1
    POP     {R1}
    MOV     R2, #7
    MOV     R7, #4
    SWI     0
    
    
_exit:
    MOV     R7, #1
    SWI     0
    
.data
copy:    .space     21
```

Edit: What is an empty label? The one filled with spaces. What's the error description? It doesn't have an error because the syntax is correct, it's the logic that it missing. I'm also aware that LDR R3, =copy isn't copying R3 in copy. I'm looking for an alternative to this line. I have no idea where to start. I would like to put whatever is at R3 into copy.

Comment: What is an “empty label” supposed to be?  Labels just mark locations in your program.  They aren't storage.  However, they can label locations in storage.  Also, “it doesn't work” is not an error description.  Please give a detailed error description.

Comment: Also note that `ldr r3, =copy` loads the address of `copy` into `r3`.  It does not copy your string.  To copy your string, you need to iterate over the characters in the string and copy them one by one.

Comment: copy is not empty, copy is a label and there are bytes after that address.

Comment: look up instructions like ldr r3,[r4] and str r3,[r5]  or ldm/stm ldrd/strd, etc.